# Is a date filter being applied to search results from YouTube Data API automatically?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get search results of videos on specific topics and specific locations from the YouTube data API. An example query for this format would be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&location=38.8%2C116.4&locationRadius=100km&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&q=game&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

In this case the `totalResults` count shows a relatively large number, the returned results are few.

In another case (same as above but with a broader location radius):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&location=38.8%2C116.4&locationRadius=1000km&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&q=game&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

The results are only from the recent few months, though I haven't specified a time filter.

It looks like somehow a date filter is getting applied to the content. I am pretty sure this issue was not there a few weeks ago. Has there been any change to how the API behaves or am I encountering a bug?